# Recording navigation with jmeter without page extensions

Tags: tomcat, jmeter

I want to do recording with JMeter for my application that run locally for load test.

I have followed the steps that are given in below link.

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf

  1. In my application I did not use extension(i.e. http://yourhost.com/urlrewrite/feedback is do not have .jsp).
  2. If I am starting my tomcat 0n 8080 and starting JMeter also then its saying port 8080 is use.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can match everything (all urls) by leaving both "URL Patterns To Include" and "URL Patterns To Exclude" blank.  But this will mean your test plan will also include requests for things like png images, js javascript files, etc, that your page includes. You can manually remove these from your test plan later if you want.
2. The "HTTP Proxy Server" component in JMeter has a Port setting. You can change this, so your JMeter proxy uses a different port to 8080.